# Line Integral with two methods

Tags: analysis, vector-fields

I need some advice. The problem is to Evaluate the line integral by two methods $(a)$ directly and $(b)$ using Green's Theorem

$$\oint_c y^2 \, d x + x^2 y \, dy $$
$C $ is the rectangle with vertices $\left( 0,0\right)$ , $\left( 5,0\right)$ , $\left( 5,4\right)$ and $\left( 0,4\right)$

So at first I solved using Green's Theorem
$$ \int_0^{4} \int_{0}^{5} 2 x y - 2 y \, d x \, d y = 120$$

After that I tried to solve this problem using vector equations.
$$r_1(t) = <5t;0> \Rightarrow \, dx = 5 \, dt \text{ and } \, dy = 0 \,dt$$

$$r_2(t) = <5;4t>  \Rightarrow \, dx = 0 \, dt \text{ and } \, dy = 4 \,dt$$

$$r_3(t) = <5-5t;4>  \Rightarrow \, dx = -5 \, dt \text{ and } \, dy = 0 \,dt $$
$$r_4(t) = <0;4-4t>  \Rightarrow \, dx = 0 \, dt \text{ and } \, dy = -4 \,dt$$

And then just calculated $4$ integrals and added them.

And after calculations I am not getting $120$. So can you tell me if  the idea is correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \displaystyle \oint_c y^2 \, d x + x^2 y \, dy$

$C$  is the rectangle with vertices $(0,0) , (5,0) , (5,4)$ and $(0,4)$.

The line integral from $(0,0)$ to $(5, 0)$ is zero as $y = 0$.

$r_2(t) = (5, 4t), 0 \leq t \leq 1, r_2'(t) = (0, 4)$

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 5^2 \cdot 4t \cdot 4 ~ dt = 200$

$r_3(t) = (5-5t, 4), 0 \leq t \leq 1, r_3'(t) = ( -5, 0)$

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 4^2 \cdot - 5 ~ dt = - 80$

The line integral from $(0, 4)$ to $(0, 0)$ is zero as $x = 0$ and $dx = 0$.

That sums to $120$.